# How to generically proxy localhost to an authenticated remote backend?

Tags: authentication, proxy, http-proxy

Most articles or answers I find deal with proxying a localhost url to a localhost backend server on a different port, or to a non-authenticated remote server (no log in required). However, what I am unable to find is how to generically proxy requests to a remote server that requires authentication.

A common practice in web development is to create multiple instances of the app (beta/dev, integration/test, production, etc.) so you can test and deploy gradually before the code hits production. Each instances has it's own backend server and data that is typically accessible through public urls (e.g. beta.app.com/api).

The difficulty comes when the api requires user authentication to access. Setting up a typical proxy won't work as the credentials from localhost will be different from those of the remote server.

What I want to be able to do is be able to proxy all localhost api calls to one of the remote servers so I don't have to run a backend server locally, or be able to test local code against remote data (great for debugging prod only bugs). What I don't want to have to do is hardcode credentials to the remote server into the proxy, as that won't work for anyone else who runs the app locally (so no hardcoding proxy headers that add auth cookies, etc.).

I image the solution will require more than just a proxy to work, and that's fine. Assume I have full control of both the frontend and backend and can make any changes needed to make this work.